# Can´t boot mcafee endpoint encryption partition

Tags: boot, partitioning

I have a notebook with Mcafee Endpoint Encryption on Windows 7. Yesterday, I made another partition and installed Ubuntu. But the notebook always boot to Ubuntu, instead of reconizing the partition that is encrypted. So I removed Ubuntu with gparted live cd, and now I have a partition that is encrypted and one that is free. But when I start the notebook it says "error: no such partition. entering rescue mode... grub recue".

All I want is to boot to the encrypted partition so I can use Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty late response, but the behavior you're seeing, to me, indicates:

- You installed Ubuntu's default bootloader during your install process
- This overwrote the Windows/MEE bootloader, which does something magical to boot your encrypted Windows partition
- `grub2` (or whatever Ubuntu uses) has no issue recognizing your Linux partition, but doesn't know what to do with the encrypted Windows partition.

I think you're out of luck unless you have a backup of the original MBR. I have McAfee Endpoint Encryption (formerly SafeBoot) on my computer as well, and wrote the article on [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dual_boot_with_Windows_when_SafeBoot_is_installed) regarding how I set up a dual boot system, working around MEE.

I don't quite understand how MEE works, but I believe the MBR is encrypted somehow, and then knows to look for something on the `C:` drive to allow for boot decryption. That could be completely wrong, but the point is that from my experience, you'll never be able to boot Windows from `grub[2]`, `syslinux`, `lilo`, etc. "natively" because they can't access whatever it is that MEE can get to on the encrypted `C:` drive.

During my first attempt (~3 work computers ago), I took a queue from [this post](http://kennethdalbjerg.dk/2013/11/19/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-7-with-safeboot-mcafee-endpoint-encryption) to backup the original MBR (or maybe it was [this one](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1039401) that prompted...):

> Next, need to capture the Safeboot boot loader than is in the MBR (dd if=/dev/sda of=/media/memstick/safeboot.mbr bs=512 count=1). This will be used as part of chain loading with grub later.

He uses it to chainload Windows, so it can boot via the original encrypted MEE boot code that does it's "magic." I used it simply to restore the MBR when something went awry, using [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to chainload `syslinux` instead (once Linux was installed).

In any case, the point is that without a copy of the original encrypted MBR, I think you're out of luck. You can google around a bit on McAfee docs, as there are ways to decrypt with a daily code or something. For me, this was done on a work computer, so the time I borked my system during installation was simply resolved by asking them to re-image it (after apologizing for the inconvenience).